# Delays on startups and shutdowns (after removing swap partition)

Tags: startup, shutdown, microsoft-windows, swap

Recently I have to delete my swap partition in order to install Windows 10 (install srceen said something 'bout having too much partition on my drive). Now every time I run elementary os or other linux distro (which have been reinstalled due to shenanigans and worked OK), there's like a pause (over 10s of something) of just the blinking cursor before the computer prints out this line:

> Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device

and start booting normally. And as for shutdowns, the system prints something like

"a stop job is running for section c2 of user user XXXX (xx/24s)"

before shutdown. For the former issues, I have tried creating a swap file (with the instructions form [This article](https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/)), then change /etc/fstab to:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=fa6b3b5e-904d-4a50-8c4f-5993c38937f2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#disable swap
#UUID=4dcc1eb2-c8dc-4b4a-bed3-ab53f581a0ff none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

and <del>edited "/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume" to "RESUME=UUID=none"</del> commented (basically deleted) the line with seemingly no effect to the problem.

Another thing is that, in the installation of Windows, I accidentally deleted all my Linux partitions. So I aborted the installation, tried to recover the partitions with testdisk- which thankfully worked- then started the installation again. I did run `sudo fsck -f` (which turns in clean) and the root partitions' UUID seems to be unchanged so I don't know if this have anything to do with the problems.

It isn't that much an serious issue to me as it's still relatively quick to log in/out of the os. But I would be more happy if those delay were fix and gone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the swap-partition is still listet in your /etc/fstab ?
If so, try to uncomment this line in /etc/fstab with a hashmark and reboot.
Messed up UUIDs in a fstab can cause this mentioned behaviour.

Comment: I did do that quite some time ago then add this `/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0` for the swap file. I am wondering if there is other places that has outdated UUIDs which might have caused this.

Comment: I don't know if defaults is the correct mount option. Did you try "sw" instead, like this entry for example?:
"/swapfile none swap sw 0 0"

Another question is, do you really need a swapfile?

Comment: I'll try that. And yes, although it's rarely been a problem to me, you never know when you'll need some sort of RAM overflow (that's what swaps does, right?). And also I only have 4 G of RAM. :P

Comment: Update: No effect. I even tried to comment the line (basically make the system ignore that line) then reboot and nothing happen. So I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Normally you should see the partition he is complaining about in the message. 

Use blkid and compare the UUIDs. Maybe there is a mistake in an entry. 

Did you update your initramfs after changing to swapfile?